# What is the proper way of mongoose populate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello im new to nodejs and mongoose, i need help in mongoose populate, please help me to understand. Thanks in Advance!
here is my schema's

**PropertySchema.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose
require('./MemberSchema')

const propertySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  pname: String,
  ptype: String,
  price: Number,
  owner: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Members' }
})


const Props = mongoose.model('Property', propertySchema)

module.exports = Property
```

**MemberSchema.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose
require('./PropertySchema')

const memberSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  fname: String,
  lname: String,
  dob: Number,
  email: String,
  address: String,
  phone: Number,
  memtype: String,
  username: {type: String, required: true},
  password: {type: String, required:true},
  properties: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Property' }]
})

const Members = mongoose.model('Members', memberSchema)

module.exports = Members
```

**addPropertyRoutes.js**

```
router.post('/add', isAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
  const props = new Property({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    pname: req.body.pname,
    ptype: req.body.ptype,
    price: req.body.price,
    owner: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
  })
  props.save( (err, props) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Unable to register your data: ' + err)
      throw err
    }
    console.log('Property Added Successful!')
    res.redirect('/property/add')
  })
})
```

Im using mongoose 3.6 and expressjs.

When i check my Robo 3t after adding properties it shows like this check this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, what is your question exactly?

Comment: Hello, and sorry for my mistake, i already edited the title and indicate my question. By the way Thank you sir :)

Comment: I guess you mean why properties is an empty array? They are not doubly linked automatically. So you will still need to do something like member.properties.push(propId); and then member.save();

Comment: if that is the case you can chain populate method after find and pass object with {path: 'your path', model: ''}, to get the approprite result

Comment: I actually thought this was a wildlife question at first :)

Comment: @HenryLiu i tried what you say but im getting an **TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

Answer (score 0):

In your, property schema you have to store ownerId, not to generate new ObjectId. 
The proper way to do Populate in mongoose, you can find it [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Answer (score 0):

i think the solution is this:

change your addPropertyRoutes into this :)

```
router.post('/add', isAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
      const member = req.user
      Members.findOne({})
      const props = new Property({
        pname: req.body.pname,
        ptype: req.body.ptype,
        price: req.body.price,
        owner: member._id
      })
      props.save( (err, props) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Unable to register your data: ' + err)
          throw err
        }
        console.log('Registration Successful!')
        res.redirect('/property/add')
      })
    })
```

Your Welcome from noobs

Comment: properties still has an empty array :(